# tracking multiple objects using kalman filter in opencv

Tags: opencv

I am successfully able to track single object using kalman filter. Now i want track two objects. I have no idea how to apply kalman filter for two objects. Can anyone please help.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to have a separate kalman filter for each object. So, instead of using one kalman filter, use an array (or any other collection) of them.

Comment: Can you share code. how did you track simple object?

Answer (score 7):

Take a look on my implementation.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2fW5TmAtAXM

Sources on GitHub: https://github.com/Smorodov/Multitarget-tracker

Here is main.cpp file for the project to track 2 targets:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
//#include "BackgroundSubtract.h"
//#include "Detector.h"

#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h>
#include "CTracker.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

float X=0,Y=0;
float Xmeasured=0,Ymeasured=0;
RNG rng;
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Mouse callback
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void mv_MouseCallback(int event, int x, int y, int /*flags*/, void* /*param*/)
{
    if(event == cv::EVENT_MOUSEMOVE)
    {
        X=(float)x;
        Y=(float)y;
    }
}

int main(int ac, char** av)
{
    int k=0;
    // Track colors
    Scalar Colors[]={Scalar(255,0,0),Scalar(0,255,0),Scalar(0,0,255),Scalar(255,255,0),Scalar(0,255,255),Scalar(255,255,255)};
    namedWindow("Video");
    Mat frame=Mat(800,800,CV_8UC3);

    VideoWriter vw=VideoWriter::VideoWriter("output.mpeg", CV_FOURCC('P','I','M','1'), 20, frame.size());

    // Attach mouse callback to window
    setMouseCallback("Video",mv_MouseCallback,0);

    CTracker tracker(0.2,0.5,60.0,25,25);
    float alpha=0;
    while(k!=27)
    {
        frame=Scalar::all(0);

        // add some noise (simulation of real measurement)
        Xmeasured=X+rng.gaussian(2.0);
        Ymeasured=Y+rng.gaussian(2.0);

        // Add tracking targets
        // sin and cos added for more fun :)
        vector<Point2d> pts;
        pts.push_back(Point2d(Xmeasured+100.0*sin(-alpha),Ymeasured+100.0*cos(-alpha))); // 1-st target coords
        pts.push_back(Point2d(Xmeasured+100.0*sin(alpha),Ymeasured+100.0*cos(alpha)));   // 2-nd target coords 
        //pts.push_back(Point2d(Xmeasured+100.0*sin(alpha/2.0),Ymeasured+100.0*cos(alpha/2.0)));
        //pts.push_back(Point2d(Xmeasured+100.0*sin(alpha/3.0),Ymeasured+100.0*cos(alpha/1.0)));
        alpha+=0.05;

    // Draw targets
    for(int i=0; i<pts.size(); i++)
    {
    circle(frame,pts[i],3,Scalar(0,255,0),1,CV_AA);
    }

    // Update tracks
        tracker.Update(pts);

    //  cout << tracker.tracks.size()  << endl;

    // Draw tracks
        for(int i=0;i<tracker.tracks.size();i++)
        {
            if(tracker.tracks[i]->trace.size()>1)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<tracker.tracks[i]->trace.size()-1;j++)
                {
                    line(frame,tracker.tracks[i]->trace[j],tracker.tracks[i]->trace[j+1],Colors[i%6],2,CV_AA);
                }
            }
        }
        imshow("Video",frame);

        // write videoframe to file
        // vw << frame;
        k=waitKey(10);
    }
    vw.release();
    destroyAllWindows();
    return 0;


}
```

Comment: I am not able to understand the code properly, can anyone please give me the source code to track two objects using kalman filter in opencv.

Comment: I've corrected my answer and translated some comments.

Comment: Can u please give me the code for tracking two objects using kalman filter. In my code i am able to detect two objects. I have used backgroundsubtractor and i am able to draw bounding box for it. In my code predict function is working but we dont know how to apply estimate function can you please help. waiting for your reply. Thank you.

Comment: Can you send me your detector and test video? I'll try to combine the tracker and your detector.

Comment: Sorry i cant upload the test video. Is there any other way that you can help me

Comment: But if you will not provide interface of your functions I can't embed them into my code. And it would be good if I have ability to test the result code.

Comment: I am not able to upload the video file and source. I am not getting permission.

Comment: You can send it to my e-mail: andreysmorodov#list.ru (# change to @).

Comment: Tracking can be simplified into 4 categories that is region based, active contour based, feature extraction and model based. Can we consider Kalman filter as one of the approach in model based methods.

Comment: Kalman filter is a statistical filter it is not a tracker at all. Tracker is a complex thing consisting of detector (provide taget coordinates), assignment algorithm (assign labels to targets from detector), and filter (noise removing, and prediction of next target coordinates). All points you enumerate above are detector categories.

Comment: When I am trying to install opencv. When i run the cmd.exe command and run following command "c:\dev\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe" the files starts generating and when it comes to 80% it gives continues error and stops. What can be done for this.

Comment: Can anyone give me link for downloading matlab software to work on image processing software.

Comment: Not the product i want to work on matlab projects. I want to install it

Comment: MATLAB commercial product, you can try use free software like GNU Octave, or, may be it'll be even better for prototyping use ImageJ.

Comment: Can it be Matlab independent. I do not have Matlab.

Comment: It is MATLAB independent. MATLAB files only for reference.